# How to submit a form on a child HTML window, then call a Javascript function on the parent window, then close the child window

Tags: javascript, html

All,

This should be a pretty simple question, but I haven't found quite the answer I'm looking for yet.

I have a parent HTML window. When a user clicks a button on that window, it opens a child window (e.g., "childA.asp")

That child window includes a form. Here's what I'd like to happen when the user submits that form:

1. The data in the form is saved
2. The child window closes
3. The parent window updates to reflect the new data

How can I implement this?

Should the form on childA.asp post the data to another page (e.g., "childB.asp"), which saves the data, then calls a JavaScript function on the parent window notifying it to update, then close itself?

If so, how would you do this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript code in your child page can refer to the parent page via `window.opener`.  Thus what could happen is this:

1. Child page submits the form to the server
2. Server does stuff and responds with a "result" page
3. The "result" page is either the original form with errors, or else a little page with just a `<script>` block to do:

   ```
   window.opener.timeToReloadYourself();
   window.close();
   ```